# In Jetpack compose, whenever clicked bottom navigation item then app crashed, why?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-navigation

*I am beginner for jetpack composed, Just start application and create daily one screen. Todays create bottom navigation bar and all item shown on screen but whenever clicked bottom item then app crashed.
please seen code file. and help me.*

```
@SuppressLint("UnusedMaterial3ScaffoldPaddingParameter")
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun DashboardScreen(navController: NavHostController) {
    Scaffold(
        topBar = { CustomToolbarScreen(navController = navController, title = "Dashboard", false) }
    ) { innerPadding ->
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier.padding(innerPadding),
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
        ) {
            Scaffold (
                bottomBar = {
                    BottomAppBar {
                        BottomNavigation()
                    }
                }
            ) {
                NavigationGraph()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

*preview of dashboard screen*

[image: bottom navigation]

*When item clicked code*

```
@Composable
fun NavigationGraph(){
        val navController = rememberNavController()
        NavHost(navController =navController , startDestination = BottomNavItem.Home.screen_route){
                composable(BottomNavItem.Home.screen_route) {
                        HomeScreen()
                }
                composable(BottomNavItem.Call.screen_route) {
                        CallScreen()
                }
                composable(BottomNavItem.Profile.screen_route) {
                        ProfileScreen()
                }
                composable(BottomNavItem.Favorite.screen_route) {
                        FavoriteScreen()
                }
        }
}
```

*Navigation item code*

```
@Composable
fun BottomNavigation(){
    val navController = rememberNavController()
    val selectedTab = remember { mutableStateOf(0) }
    val items = listOf(
        BottomNavItem.Home,
        BottomNavItem.Call,
        BottomNavItem.Profile,
        BottomNavItem.Favorite
    )
    val navBackStackEntry by navController.currentBackStackEntryAsState()
    val currentDestination = navBackStackEntry?.destination
    NavigationBar {
        items.forEach { item ->
            AddItem(
                screen = item,
                selectedTab = selectedTab,
                navController = navController
            )
        }
    }
}
@Composable
fun RowScope.AddItem(
    screen: BottomNavItem,
    selectedTab: MutableState<Int>,
    navController: NavHostController
) {
    NavigationBarItem(
        label = {
            Text(text = screen.title, fontSize = 9.sp)
        },
        icon = {
            Icon(imageVector = screen.icon, contentDescription = screen.title)
        },
        selected = selectedTab == screen,
        //selected = currentDestination?.hierarchy?.any { it.route == screen.screen_route } == true,
        alwaysShowLabel = true,
        onClick = {
            navController.navigate(screen.screen_route) {
                navController.graph.findStartDestination().route?.let {
                    popUpTo(it){
                        saveState = true
                    }
                }
                launchSingleTop = true
                restoreState = true
            }
            /*when (screen.screen_route == screen.title) {

                (screen.screen_route == "Home") -> {
                    navController.navigate(BottomNavItem.Home.screen_route)
                }
                (screen.screen_route == "Call") -> {
                    navController.navigate(BottomNavItem.Call.screen_route)
                }
                (screen.screen_route == "Profile") -> {
                    navController.navigate(BottomNavItem.Profile.screen_route)
                }
                (screen.screen_route == "Favorite") -> {
                    navController.navigate(BottomNavItem.Favorite.screen_route)
                }
                else -> {}
            }*/
        },
        colors = NavigationBarItemDefaults.colors(),
        modifier = Modifier.background(colorPrimary)
    )
}
```

*Getting the result: - *

*You must call setGraph() before calling getGraph() in jetpack compose*

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                 Process: com.appynitty.taxy, PID: 5994
                 java.lang.IllegalStateException: You must call setGraph() before calling getGraph()
                    at androidx.navigation.NavController.getGraph(NavController.kt:94)
                    at com.appynitty.taxy.navigation_connection.BottomNavigationKt$AddItem$1$1.invoke(BottomNavigation.kt:64)
                    at com.appynitty.taxy.navigation_connection.BottomNavigationKt$AddItem$1$1.invoke(BottomNavigation.kt:63)
                    at androidx.navigation.NavOptionsBuilderKt.navOptions(NavOptionsBuilder.kt:30)
                    at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.kt:2182)
                    at com.appynitty.taxy.navigation_connection.BottomNavigationKt$AddItem$1.invoke(BottomNavigation.kt:63)
                    at com.appynitty.taxy.navigation_connection.BottomNavigationKt$AddItem$1.invoke(BottomNavigation.kt:52)
                    at androidx.compose.foundation.ClickablePointerInputNode$pointerInput$3.invoke-k-4lQ0M(Clickable.kt:895)
                    at androidx.compose.foundation.ClickablePointerInputNode$pointerInput$3.invoke(Clickable.kt:889)
                    at androidx.compose.foundation.gestures.TapGestureDetectorKt$detectTapAndPress$2$1.invokeSuspend(TapGestureDetector.kt:255)
                    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
                    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTaskKt.resume(DispatchedTask.kt:177)
                    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTaskKt.dispatch(DispatchedTask.kt:166)
                    at kotlinx.coroutines.CancellableContinuationImpl.dispatchResume(CancellableContinuationImpl.kt:474)
                    at kotlinx.coroutines.CancellableContinuationImpl.resumeImpl(CancellableContinuationImpl.kt:508)
                    at kotlinx.coroutines.CancellableContinuationImpl.resumeImpl$default(CancellableContinuationImpl.kt:497)
                    at kotlinx.coroutines.CancellableContinuationImpl.resumeWith(CancellableContinuationImpl.kt:368)
                    at
                 androidx.compose.ui.input.pointer.SuspendingPointerInputModifierNodeImpl$PointerEventHandlerCoroutine.offerPointerEvent(SuspendingPointerInputFilter.kt:665)
                    at androidx.compose.ui.input.pointer.SuspendingPointerInputModifierNodeImpl.dispatchPointerEvent(SuspendingPointerInputFilter.kt:544)
                    at androidx.compose.ui.input.pointer.SuspendingPointerInputModifierNodeImpl.onPointerEvent-H0pRuoY(SuspendingPointerInputFilter.kt:566)
                    at androidx.compose.foundation.AbstractClickablePointerInputNode.onPointerEvent-H0pRuoY(Clickable.kt:855)
                    at androidx.compose.foundation.AbstractClickableNode.onPointerEvent-H0pRuoY(Clickable.kt:703)
                    at androidx.compose.ui.input.pointer.Node.dispatchMainEventPass(HitPathTracker.kt:317)
                    at androidx.compose.ui.input.pointer.Node.dispatchMainEventPass(HitPathTracker.kt:303)
                    at androidx.compose.ui.input.pointer.Node.dispatchMainEventPass(HitPathTracker.kt:303)
                    at androidx.compose.ui.input.pointer.Node.dispatchMainEventPass(HitPathTracker.kt:303)
                    at androidx.compose.ui.input.pointer.Node.dispatchMainEventPass(HitPathTracker.kt:303)
                    at androidx.compose.ui.input.pointer.Node.dispatchMainEventPass(HitPathTracker.kt:303)
                    at androidx.compose.ui.input.pointer.Node.dispatchMainEventPass(HitPathTracker.kt:303)
                    at androidx.compose.ui.input.pointer.NodeParent.dispatchMainEventPass(HitPathTracker.kt:183)
                    at androidx.compose.ui.input.pointer.HitPathTracker.dispatchChanges(HitPathTracker.kt:102)
                    at androidx.compose.ui.input.pointer.PointerInputEventProcessor.process-BIzXfog(PointerInputEventProcessor.kt:96)
                    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeView.sendMotionEvent-8iAsVTc(AndroidComposeView.android.kt:1446)
                    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeView.handleMotionEvent-8iAsVTc(AndroidComposeView.android.kt:1398)
                    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeView.dispatchTouchEvent(AndroidComposeView.android.kt:1338)
                    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3184)
                    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2834)
                    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3184)
                    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2834)
                    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3184)
10:32:23.549  E     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2834)
                    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3184)
                    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2834)
                    at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:572)
                    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1895)
                    at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:4274)
                    at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:530)
                    at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:15165)
                    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6919)
                    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:6698)
                    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:6135)
                    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:6192)
                    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:6158)
                    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:6323)
                    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:6166)
                    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:6380)
                    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:6139)
                    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:6192)
                    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:6158)
                    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:6166)
                    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:6139)
                    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:9271)
                    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:9211)
                    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:9168)
                    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:9416)
                    at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:280)
                    at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
                    at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:340)
                    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:168)
                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:299)
                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8280)
                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:576)
                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1073)
                    Suppressed: kotlinx.coroutines.internal.DiagnosticCoroutineContextException: [androidx.compose.ui.platform.MotionDurationScaleImpl@5712609, androidx.compose.runtime.BroadcastFrameClock@eba200e, StandaloneCoroutine{Cancelling}@3d81a2f, AndroidUiDispatcher@a57a83c]
```

Comment: Removed `android-studio` tag as that tag is for issues/problems with the Android Studio product. This question has nothing to do with the Android Studio product.

Answer (score 1):

This behaviour is due to the creation of several navigation controllers along the composable hierarchy. You are creating 3 NavHostController objects in your tree but you should create only one at the very top of the hierarchy instead in order to syncronize all of the composables and the screens in the navigation tree.

These 3 controllers I'm mentioning are: one passed as parameter in DashboardScreen, and the two that are being created inside NavigationGraph and BottomNavigation composables.

When you click on a botton nav item, the bottom nav bar is referencing to the latest navController which is not connected to the other 2 nav controllers. That's why the error says you are trying to setGraph() before getGraph(), because there is no such NavHost configured with the same navController you are using in the Bottom Navigation Bar.

In order to fix this problem, just pass the DashboardScreen parameter to both of the 2 composables NavigationGraph and BottomNavigation as a parameter, and get rid off the other 2 navController objects created inside the inner two composables.

```
@SuppressLint("UnusedMaterial3ScaffoldPaddingParameter")
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun DashboardScreen(navController: NavHostController) {
    Scaffold(
        topBar = { CustomToolbarScreen(navController = navController, title = "Dashboard", false) }
    ) { innerPadding ->
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier.padding(innerPadding),
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
        ) {
            Scaffold (
                bottomBar = {
                    BottomAppBar {
                        BottomNavigation(navController)
                    }
                }
            ) {
                NavigationGraph(navController)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Android Developers official site' recommendation is as follows:

> "You should create the NavController in the place in your composable
> hierarchy where all composables that need to reference it have access
> to it. This follows the principles of state hoisting and allows you to
> use the NavController and the state it provides via
> currentBackStackEntryAsState() to be used as the source of truth for
> updating composables outside of your screens. See Integration with the
> bottom navbar for an example of this functionality."

Source: [Navigating with Compose](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/navigation)

Comment: nice, thank you bro